# the sum of the convolutions with themselves of the coprimes of composite $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Convolve the coprimes with themselves of composite n and find their sum.  Let n =$5\cdot2^k$ with $k>0$ and use the example for $n=10$: $1\cdot1 + (3*1+1*3) + (7\cdot1+3\cdot3+1\cdot7) + (9\cdot1+7\cdot3+3\cdot7+1\cdot9)
=90$, which is divisble by 10. This is also true for $n=20,40,80$ that each divides the sum of its convolution of coprimes with themselves.  These sums in order are $1300, 19080$, and $289680$.  Will this divisibility continue for all values of $k$?  Can it be true of other $n$ of different prime factors?

Comment: when $n=20$, the sum is $1300$,  not $3740$  right?

Comment: This can be shown to be true when $n$ is a prime larger than $3$.

Comment: This also seems to be true with $n=7\cdot 3^k$.

Comment: When $n=7\cdot 3^k$, the sum actually seems to be divisible by $8n$.

Comment: A sufficient condition for $n$ to have this property seems to be that $n$ be coprime with $6$.

Comment: Yes, should be 1300..got lost in the paperwork.  Some numerical experiments for different prime factors for n  would confirm these examples.

Comment: The fifth term in that sequence is 30, but it does NOT work for 30.  Find the simple method that gives the sum of all convolutions and let a machine play with it to find successes.

Comment: In the example for $n=10$, why don't you get terms $7\times7$ and $9\times9$? Also, $3\times9$ and $9\times3$? and $7\times9$ and $9\times7$?

Comment: Envision 9,7,3,1 below 1,3,7,9 and slide the latter from right to left over the former.  You then multiply vertically 1*1 + 1*3 +1*7 + 1*9=20; next 3*1+3*3+3*7=21=33; and continue with remaining 7 and 9 to see that you do not get the terms you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Hereafter is a proof of the following proposition:

> Let $n,m$ be natural numbers and let
>   $$f(n):=\sum_{\underset{\underset{ (i,n)=(j,n)=1 } { i+j\le n}} {0\le
>  i,j \le n }}  ij .$$ Let $p$ be a prime number. We have: 
>   $$f(p^n)\equiv 0 \bmod p^n \iff   p>3.$$ Moreover, when $p$ is odd, we
>   have:  $$f(2^mp^n)\equiv 0 \bmod 2^mp^n \iff   p\equiv 1 \bmod 4.$$

which answers the OP, and constitutes a partial result for the previous conjecture on the characterization of the $n$ satisfying $f(n) \equiv 0 \bmod n$.

**Start of proof.** The proof uses the classical closed forms for the sum of powers of integers for the exponent $1,2\text{ and }3$. We have:
\begin{align*}
f(p^n)&=\sum_{\underset{\underset{ (i, p^n)=(j, p^n)=1 } { i+j\le  p^n}} {0\le i,j \le  p^n }}  ij=\sum_{\underset{\underset{ i,j\not{\equiv}0\bmod p}{ i+j\le p^n}} {1\le i,j \le p^n-1 } } ij\\
f(p^n)&=\sum_{k=2}^{p^n} \sum_{\underset{j,k-j\not{\equiv}0 \bmod p} {1\le j \le k-1 } } j(k-j)
\end{align*}
We have introduced the new summation index $k=i+j$. Then,
\begin{align*}
f(p^n)&=\sum_{\underset{j\not{\equiv}  0 \bmod  p} {1\le j \le p^n-1 } } j\sum_{\underset{k-j\not{\equiv}  0 \bmod   p} {j+1\le k \le p^n } }(k-j)\\
f(p^n)&=\sum_{\underset{j\not{\equiv}  0 \bmod  p} {1\le j \le p^n-1 } } j \sum_{\underset{u \not{\equiv}  0 \bmod  p} {1\le u \le p^n-j } }u\\
f(p^n)&=\sum_{1\le j \le p^n-1 } j \sum_{\underset{u \not{\equiv}  0 \bmod  p} {1\le u \le p^n-j } }u-\sum_{\underset{j\equiv  0 \bmod  p} {1\le j \le p^n-1 } } j \sum_{\underset{u \not{\equiv}  0 \bmod  p} {1\le u \le p^n-j } }u\\
f(p^n)&=\sum_{1\le j \le p^n-1 } j \sum_{1\le u \le p^n-j } u-\sum_{1\le j \le p^n-1 } j \sum_{\underset{u \equiv  0 \bmod  p} {1\le u \le p^n-j } }u\\
&-\sum_{\underset{j\equiv  0 \bmod  p} {1\le j \le p^n-1 } } j \sum_{1\le u \le p^n-j }u+\sum_{\underset{j\equiv  0 \bmod  p} {1\le j \le p^n-1 } } j \sum_{\underset{u \equiv  0 \bmod  p} {1\le u \le p^n-j } }u\\
f(p^n)&=\sum_{1\le j \le p^n-1 } j \sum_{1\le u \le p^n-j } u-2\sum_{\underset{j\equiv  0 \bmod  p} {1\le j \le p^n-1 } } j \sum_{1\le u \le p^n-j }u+\sum_{\underset{j\equiv  0 \bmod  p} {1\le j \le p^n-1 } } j \sum_{\underset{u \equiv  0 \bmod  p} {1\le u \le p^n-j } }u\\
f(p^n)&=\sum_{1\le j \le p^n-1 }\frac{j(p^n-j)(p^n-j+1)}{2}\\
&-2p\sum_{1\le k \le p^{n-1}-1 }  k \sum_{1\le u \le p^n-kp }u\\
&+p^2\sum_{1\le k \le p^{n-1}-1 }k \sum_{1\le \ell \le p^{n-1}-k } \ell\\
f(p^n)&=\sum_{1\le j \le p^n-1 }\frac{j(p^n-j)(p^n-j+1)}{2}\\
&-2p\sum_{1\le k \le p^{n-1}-1 } \frac{k(p^n-kp)(p^n-kp+1)}{2}\\
&+p^2\sum_{1\le k \le p^{n-1}-1 } \frac{k(p^{n-1}-k)(p^{n-1}-k+1)}{2}\\
\end{align*}
We expand the sums on the right hand side and replace the sums of powers by their well-known closed forms, and then, after some elementary algebric manipulations, we find:
\begin{align*}
f(p^n)=p^n\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)\frac{ p^{3 n - 2}(p-1)  + 2 p^{2 n - 1}+2p^{n}+2}{12}
\end{align*}
If $p=2$, $f(2^n)=2^n\frac{ 2^{3 n - 3}  + 2^{2 n-1}+2^{n}+1}{12}$. 
But $f(2)=1$ and if $n>1$, $2^{3 n - 3}  +2^{2 n-1}+2^{n}+1$ is odd and a fortiori not multiple of $12$, then $2^n$ does not divide $f(2^n)$.

If $p=3$, $f(3^n)=3^n\frac{ 3^{3 n - 2}  + 3^{2 n - 1}+3^{n}+1}{6}$.
But  $ 3^{3 n - 2}  + 3^{2 n - 1}+3^{n}+1$ is not divisible by $3$ and a fortiori not by $6$, then $3^n$ does not divide $f(3^n)$.

If $p>3$, we will show that $p^n$ divides $f(p^n)$. In that case, $p \equiv a \bmod 12$, whith $a= 1,5,7 \text{ or }-1$.

If $a=1$, $\frac{p-1}{4}$ is integer, and  $f(p^n)=p^n\left(\frac{p-1}{4}\right)\frac{ 2p^{3 n - 2}(p-1)  + 4 p^{2 n - 1}+4p^{n}+4}{12}$ and
\begin{align*}  2p^{3 n - 2}(p-1)  + 4 p^{2 n - 1}+4p^{n}+4 &\equiv 0+ 4+4+4\equiv0  \bmod 12
\end{align*}
If $a=5$, $\frac{p-1}{4}$ is integer, and  $f(p^n)=p^n\left(\frac{p-1}{4}\right)\frac{ 2p^{3 n - 2}(p-1)  + 4 p^{2 n - 1}+4p^{n}+4}{12}$ and
\begin{align*}  2p^{3 n - 2}(p-1)  + 4 p^{2 n - 1}+4p^{n}+4 &\equiv 4(2\cdot5^{3 n - 2} + 5^{2 n - 1}+5^{n}+1) \bmod 12\\
2\cdot5^{3 n - 2} + 5^{2 n - 1}+5^{n}+1&\equiv (-1)^{3 n -1} + (-1)^{2 n - 1}+(-1)^{n}+1 \bmod 3\\
&\equiv0 \bmod 3.
\end{align*}
If $a=7$,   $f(p^n)=p^n\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)\frac{ p^{3 n - 2}(p-1)  + 2 p^{2 n - 1}+2p^{n}+2}{12}$ and
\begin{align*}  p^{3 n - 2}(p-1)  + 2 p^{2 n - 1}+2p^{n}+2 &\equiv 6\cdot 7^{3 n - 2} +2 \cdot 7^{2 n - 1}+2\cdot 7^{n}+2 \bmod 12\\
3\cdot 7^{3 n - 2} + 7^{2 n - 1}+ 7^{n}+1&\equiv 3+1+1 +1 \bmod 6\\
&\equiv0 \bmod6.
\end{align*}
If $a=-1$,   $f(p^n)=p^n\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)\frac{ p^{3 n - 2}(p-1)  + 2 p^{2 n - 1}+2p^{n}+2}{12}$ and
\begin{align*}  p^{3 n - 2}(p-1)  + 2 p^{2 n - 1}+2p^{n}+2 &\equiv -2\cdot (-1)^{3 n - 2} +2 \cdot (-1)^{2 n - 1}+2\cdot (-1)^{n}+2 \bmod 12\\
- (-1)^{3 n - 2} + (-1)^{2 n - 1}+ (-1)^{n}+1&\equiv -(-1)^n-1+(-1)^n+1 \bmod 6\\
&\equiv0 \bmod6.
\end{align*}

Now, let $m,n>0$ be natural integers.
\begin{align*}
f(2^mp^n)&=\sum_{\underset{\underset{ (i,2^m p^n)=(j,2^m p^n)=1 } { i+j\le 2^m p^n}} {0\le i,j \le 2^m p^n }}  ij=\sum_{\underset{\underset{i,j \text{ odd and } i,j\not{\equiv}0\bmod p}{ i+j\le 2^mp^n}} {1\le i,j \le 2^mp^n-1 } } ij\\
f(2^mp^n)&=\sum_{k=2}^{2^mp^n} \sum_{\underset{\underset{j,k-j \text{ odd} }{j,k-j\not{\equiv}0 \bmod p}} {1\le j \le k-1 } } j(k-j)
\end{align*}
We have introduced the new summation index $k=i+j$ and we see that in the above sum, $j$ must be odd and $k$ must be even. Then,
\begin{align*}
f(2^mp^n)&=\sum_{k=1}^{2^{m-1}p^n} \sum_{\underset{2j-1,2k-2j+1\not{\equiv}  0 \bmod  p} {1\le j \le k } }(2j-1)(2k-2j+1)\\
f(2^mp^n)&=\sum_{\underset{2j-1\not{\equiv}  0 \bmod  p} {1\le j \le 2^{m-1}p^n } } (2j-1)\sum_{\underset{2k-2j+1\not{\equiv}  0 \bmod   p} {j\le k \le 2^{m-1}p^n } }(2k-2j+1)\\
f(2^mp^n)&=\sum_{\underset{2j-1\not{\equiv}  0 \bmod  p} {1\le j \le 2^{m-1}p^n } } (2j-1) \sum_{\underset{2u-1 \not{\equiv}  0 \bmod  p} {1\le u \le 2^{m-1}p^n-j+1 } } (2u-1)\\
f(2^mp^n)&=\sum_{ 1\le j \le 2^{m-1}p^n }  (2j-1) \sum_{\underset{2u-1 \not{\equiv}  0 \bmod  p} {1\le u \le 2^{m-1}p^n-j+1 } } (2u-1)-\sum_{\underset{2j-1\equiv  0 \bmod  p} {1\le j \le 2^{m-1}p^n } } (2j-1) \sum_{\underset{2u-1 \not{\equiv}  0 \bmod  p} {1\le u \le 2^{m-1}p^n-j+1 } } (2u-1)\\
f(2^mp^n)&=\sum_{ 1\le j \le 2^{m-1}p^n }  (2j-1) \sum_{1\le u \le 2^{m-1}p^n-j+1 }  (2u-1)-\sum_{ 1\le j \le 2^{m-1}p^n }  (2j-1) \sum_{\underset{2u-1 \equiv  0 \bmod  p} {1\le u \le 2^{m-1}p^n-j+1 } } (2u-1)\\
&-\sum_{\underset{2j-1\equiv  0 \bmod  p} {1\le j \le 2^{m-1}p^n } } (2j-1) \sum_{1\le u \le 2^{m-1}p^n-j+1 }  (2u-1)+\sum_{\underset{2j-1\equiv  0 \bmod  p} {1\le j \le 2^{m-1}p^n } } (2j-1) \sum_{\underset{2u-1 \equiv 0 \bmod  p} {1\le u \le 2^{m-1}p^n-j+1 } } (2u-1)\\
f(2^mp^n)&=\sum_{ 1\le j \le 2^{m-1}p^n }  (2j-1)   (2^{m-1}p^n-j+1)^2-\sum_{ 1\le j \le 2^{m-1}p^n }  (2j-1) \sum_{\underset{2u-1 \equiv  0 \bmod  p} {1\le u \le 2^{m-1}p^n-j+1 } } (2u-1)\\
&-\sum_{\underset{2j-1\equiv  0 \bmod  p} {1\le j \le 2^{m-1}p^n } } (2j-1) (2^{m-1}p^n-j+1)^2+\sum_{\underset{2j-1\equiv  0 \bmod  p} {1\le j \le 2^{m-1}p^n } } (2j-1) \sum_{\underset{2u-1 \equiv 0 \bmod  p} {1\le u \le 2^{m-1}p^n-j+1 } } (2u-1)\\
f(2^mp^n)&=\sum_{ 1\le j \le 2^{m-1}p^n }  (2j-1)   (2^{m-1}p^n-j+1)^2-\sum_{\underset{2u-1 \equiv  0 \bmod  p} {1\le u \le 2^{m-1}p^n} } (2u-1)\sum_{ 1\le j \le 2^{m-1}p^n-u+1 }  (2j-1) \\
&-\sum_{\underset{2j-1\equiv  0 \bmod  p} {1\le j \le 2^{m-1}p^n } } (2j-1) (2^{m-1}p^n-j+1)^2+\sum_{\underset{2j-1\equiv  0 \bmod  p} {1\le j \le 2^{m-1}p^n } } (2j-1) \sum_{\underset{2u-1 \equiv 0 \bmod  p} {1\le u \le 2^{m-1}p^n-j+1 } } (2u-1)\\
f(2^mp^n)&=\sum_{ 1\le j \le 2^{m-1}p^n }  (2j-1)   (2^{m-1}p^n-j+1)^2 \\
&-2\sum_{\underset{2j-1\equiv  0 \bmod  p} {1\le j \le 2^{m-1}p^n } } (2j-1) (2^{m-1}p^n-j+1)^2\\
&+\sum_{\underset{2j-1\equiv  0 \bmod  p} {1\le j \le 2^{m-1}p^n } } (2j-1) \sum_{\underset{2u-1 \equiv 0 \bmod  p} {1\le u \le 2^{m-1}p^n-j+1 } } (2u-1)\\
f(2^mp^n)&=\sum_{ 1\le j \le 2^{m-1}p^n }  (2j-1)   (2^{m-1}p^n-j+1)^2 \\
&-2p\sum_{ 1\le k \le 2^{m-1}p^{n-1}  } (2k-1) (2^{m-1}p^n-kp+\frac{p+1}{2})^2\\
&+\sum_{\underset{2j-1\equiv  0 \bmod  p} {1\le j \le 2^{m-1}p^n } } (2j-1) \sum_{\underset{2u-1 \equiv 0 \bmod  p} {1\le u \le 2^{m-1}p^n-j+1 } } (2u-1)
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
f(2^mp^n)&=\sum_{ 1\le j \le 2^{m-1}p^n }  (2j-1)   (2^{m-1}p^n-j+1)^2 \\
&-2p\sum_{ 1\le k \le 2^{m-1}p^{n-1}  } (2k-1) (2^{m-1}p^n-kp+\frac{p+1}{2})^2\\
&+p^2\sum_{ 1\le k \le 2^{m-1}p^{n-1} } (2k-1) \sum_{1\le \ell \le 2^{m-1}p^{n-1}-k+1 } (2\ell-1)\\
 f(2^mp^n)&=\sum_{ 1\le j \le 2^{m-1}p^n }  (2j-1)   (2^{m-1}p^n-j+1)^2 \\
&-2p\sum_{ 1\le k \le 2^{m-1}p^{n-1}  } (2k-1) (2^{m-1}p^n-kp+p-\frac{p-1}{2})^2\\
&+p^2\sum_{ 1\le k \le 2^{m-1}p^{n-1} } (2k-1) (2^{m-1}p^{n-1}-k+1)^2\\
 f(2^mp^n)&=\sum_{ 1\le j \le 2^{m-1}p^n }  (2j-1)   (2^{m-1}p^n-j+1)^2 \\
&+2p^2(p-1)\sum_{ 1\le k \le 2^{m-1}p^{n-1}  } (2k-1) (2^{m-1}p^{n-1}-k+1)\\
&-2p2^{2m-2}p^{2n-2} (\frac{p-1}{2})^2\\
&+(p^2-2p^3)\sum_{ 1\le k \le 2^{m-1}p^{n-1} } (2k-1) (2^{m-1}p^{n-1}-k+1)^2\\
\end{align*}
We expand the sums on the right hand side and replace the sums of powers by their well-known closed forms, and then, after some lengthy but elementary algebric manipulations, we find:
\begin{align*}
f(2^mp^n)=2^mp^n(p-1)\frac{ 8^{m - 1} (p-1) p^{3 n - 2}  + 2\cdot4^{m } p^{2 n - 1}- 2^{m - 1} (p-3) p^{n - 1}-1}{12}
\end{align*}
in particular 
\begin{align*}
f(2^m3^n)&=2^m3^n\left(8^{m - 1} 27^{n - 1}+4^{m - 1} 9^{n - 1}-\frac{1}{6}\right)
\end{align*}
which clearly shows that $2^m3^n$ does not divide $f(2^m3^n)$.

Now suppose that $p>3$,  then $p \equiv a \bmod 12$, whith $a= 1,5,7 \text{ or }11$.

If $a=1$, $ p-1 \equiv  0 \bmod 12$, and then $2^mp^n$ divides $f(2^mp^n)$.

If $a=5$, $ p-1 \equiv  0 \bmod 4$, and $p\equiv 2 \bmod3$ and then
\begin{align*}A&=8^{m - 1} (p-1) p^{3 n - 2}  + 2\cdot4^{m } p^{2 n - 1}- 2^{m - 1} (p-3) p^{n - 1}-1 \\
&\equiv2^{m - 1} 2^{3 n - 2}  +1+2^{m - 1} 2^{n - 1}-1 \pmod 3\\
&\equiv2^{m - 1} 2^{3 n - 2} +2^{m - 1} 2^{n - 1} \pmod 3\\
&\equiv2^{m - 1} 2^{n - 1}( 2^{2 n -1} +1) \pmod 3\\
&\equiv 0\pmod 3,
\end{align*} 
and then $2^mp^n$ divides $f(2^mp^n)$.

If $a=7$ or $a=11$, $ p-1$ is not divisible by $4$ and $A$ is odd clearly then $(p-1)\cdot A$ is not divisible by $4$ hence a fortiori not by $12$ and then $2^mp^n$ does not divide $f(2^mp^n)$.

We then have shown that $2^mp^n$ divides $f(2^mp^n)$ if and only if $a=1$ or $a=5$, that is if and only if $p-1\equiv 0 \bmod 4$. **End of proof.**

Comment: Much work!  Do you  think you could have saved time by examining the successes to see which qualify as solutions for 2^m * p^n?  Excellent that you  verified your work for  n up to 10,000.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but a conjecture which does not fit into a comment.

Let $q$ be a prime number and  $n=\prod_q q^{v_q}$ be the prime factorization of the integer $n >1 $. We have:

> $$ n \ \text{  does not divide}\sum_{\begin{align*} \ 0&\le i,j \le
>  n\\ &i+j\le n \\ (i,n)&=(j,n)=1  \end{align*}}ij $$ if and only if
>   \begin{align*}  &n=2^k q^m &\text{where } k>0,m \ge0 &\text{ and
>  }q\equiv 3 \bmod4 \\ \text { or }\ \ &n=2^k 3^\ell\prod_{q} q^{v_q}&\text{where } k \ge0 , \ell >0, v_q \ge 0 &\text{ and }q\equiv 5 \bmod6.
>  \end{align*}

This was verified numerically up to $n=1000$. There are $302$ such $n$ up to $1000$.

EDIT.  Actually, when $n$ does not divide the sum, it fails by little, because it seems that whatever $n$, we have:

> $$ 12\cdot\left(\sum_{\begin{align*} \ 0&\le i,j \le  n\\ &i+j\le n \\
>  (i,n)&=(j,n)=1  \end{align*}}ij \right)\equiv 0 \pmod n$$

Comment: It works for n=21 giving 2856=21*136.  It works for 10,20,40,80 which do not fit q=3mod4.  Can there be other solutions without the 2^k?  I am pleased to see that you passed this through the electrons to race around to confirm solutions.  An Exaflop machine could be exercised to extend the search.  ThanXXX again for the empiricism.

Comment: yes, there are solutions without the $2^k$. Apparently, it works for all the $3^{\ell} 7^{m}$. But it does not work for any $3^{\ell} 5^{m}$.

Comment: Do you know where you can rent an Exaflop machine for further investigation?  I wonder if there is any theorem for this or is it all just a matter of chance.  One could explore what happens if one replaced the  coprimes of n with the divisors of n.  Thus for 10 one gets 1 + 4 +14 + 40=59.

Comment: I only did numerical verifications with Mathematica on a laptop computer. I don't think that this would just be the effect of chance. It seems to me that there must be a known result here, with a proof that would only require elementary arguments.  By the way, I have also observed that multiplying the sum by $12$ seems to suffice to make the divisibility  by $n$ unconditionnally true.  See my edit.

Comment: Multiplying by 12 to give solutions to ALL=true novelty!!  ThanXXX again for the electronic detective work.  I am working on something similar and will send as a new quiry.